# Tesseract Text Extraction for Japanese Language

Tags: java, appium, tesseract, appium-ios, tess4j

While extracting the text from image for Japanese Language. The string got expanded then the actual string.I have tried to remove whitespaces also but there is no whitespaces.

Actual String : ﾍﾏﾄｸﾘｯﾄ
Extracted String : へマ卜クリツ卜

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfWmp.png)

Comment: Like Romaji, Katakana has both single and double width fonts.

Answer (score 0):

`"へマ卜クリット"` should be the extracted string. This and the actual string are the same except for the size width of the strings.

Comment: Both looks similar, but they are different while translating and comparing.

Comment: Yes, because even though “ツ” and “ッ” are the same in appearance except for the size, they differ in usage and can affect word spelling. Your program should also be able to detect small variations of the Japanese characters. The same applies to Hiragana as well.